# My Xcode is not recognizing a struct variables

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am building a example project with sections using a TableView with this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFMSovtqqUc

When this boy explain exactly at 2 minutes and 55 seconds a list of the variables created in the struct should appear in the list, but it does not.

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Attached a print screen of my Xcode displaying the values where the list of value explained in the video should appear.

[image: Xcode screen]

I am just a beginner following some video to learn to code.

Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You should really add the relevant parts of your code to the question as text, not as an image.  From the looks of it you have some typos.

Comment: You seem to have typed `(]`, which would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same it's happening to me, look

[image]

If for you it's a big problem you can put 2 parenthesis around the value you are creating

[image]

This seems to fix the problem.

### Conventions

Sorry but I could not avoid this

1. `Objects` is a wrong name for a `struct` (intact struct values are NOT objects)
2. Implicit unwrapped optionals (like the property of the struct into the example) are dangerous
3. Variable names should begin with a lowercase char
4. In Swift we don't put the name of the type of the variable inside the name of the variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, good to know, I was following the example in the video without checking the naming convention. I will try to do what you explained tonight.

Answer (score 1):

The variables aren't recognised when there is a `]` automatically provided when you type in `[` like this:

[image: Error]

If you delete the `]` as soon as it appears when you type in `[`, the error is fixed, like so:

[image]